# Sending request body in JS data - RESTfull service

Tags: angularjs, rest, jsdata

I wanted to send the request body as the JSON object to RESTful service

REST API Call:

```
GET http://localhost/api/v1/logsearch/query
{'query': {'match_all': {}}}
```

Here is my DS.defineResource

```
return DS.defineResource({
      basePath: '/api/v1',
      endpoint: '/logsearch/query',
      cacheResponse: false,
      maxAge: 0, // cache expires immediately
      name: 'log',
      idAttribute: '_id',
```

Any example that I can send the JSON object to GET Request RESTful API call using JS Data

The JSON Object that I wanted to send is :
{'query': {'match_all': {}}}

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to send data to an api you need to use post not get

Comment: ok - thanks - Do you have any example for this?

Comment: what are you using to make the call, is it angular?

Comment: yes, it is angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Answer (score 0):

to post to an object in angular to an api.

```
var obj = {'query': {'match_all': {}}};

$http.post('http://localhost/api/v1/logsearch/query', obj)
.then(function(data){//where data is the result returned by your api
  //do something with data returned here
}, function(errors){
  //handle any errors here
})
```